# Mysql query fails on remote server but works on xampp

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a php script that works well on xampp server, but when I upload to my online server it fails to execute the `mysql_query` always. weird part is that it works well offline. the registration script always returns 'failure!' on my online server.

i have downgraded the php version on my server to 5.4 but still no luck.

this is the part of the script that returns the error string:

```
$test = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(fname,lname,email,city,gender,password) VALUES('$fname','$lname','$email','$city','$gender','$passwordhash')");

    if($test) {
        echo "Registration successful";
       $last_id = mysql_insert_id();

      Registration_WelcomeMessage($fname,$email);
     }else{echo "failure!";}
```

and this is the full code:

```
                <?php
            require_once 'db.php';
            require_once 'utilities/cleaner.php';
            require_once 'reg_welcome_message.php';
            if(isset($_POST)){
                $broom = new cleaner();
            $fname = $broom->clean($_POST['fname']);
            $lname = $broom->clean($_POST['lname']);
            $email = $broom->clean($_POST['email']);
            $city = $broom->clean($_POST['city']);
            $gender = $broom->clean($_POST['gender']);
            $password = $broom->clean($_POST['password']);
            $cpassword = $broom->clean($_POST['cpassword']);
            $count = 2;
            if ($fname && $lname && $email && $city && $gender && $password && $cpassword) {
            if (preg_match("/^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/i", $email)) {
                if (strlen($password) > 5) {
                        if ($password == $cpassword) {
                        $remail = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
                        $checkemail = mysql_num_rows($remail);
                        if ($checkemail > 0) {
                            echo "This email is already registered! Please type another email...";
                        } else {    
                                    $passwordhash = hash('sha1',$password);
                                    $test = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(fname,lname,email,city,gender,password) VALUES('$fname','$lname','$email','$city','$gender','$passwordhash')");

                                    if($test) {
                                        echo "Registration successful";
                                            $last_id = mysql_insert_id();
                                        Registration_WelcomeMessage($fname,$email);
                                    }else{echo "failure!";}
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "Your passwords don't match!";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "Your password is too short! A password between 6 and 15 charachters is required!";
                }
                }else{
                        echo "Please use a valid email!";
                }
            } else {
                echo "You have to complete the form!";
            }
            }else{echo "NO data sent";}
            ?>
```

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: Have you tried checking any error logs on the server or attempted to debug? You're also using the deprecated `mysql_` functions which aren't available on new PHP versions. They're very outdated and insecure.

Comment: That API is depreciated & was removed in PHP7, it should not be used.  If its available mysql_error() will explain the issue.

Comment: Post the eventually error message posted by the server

Comment: no error message   @cteski and Alex k. i am aware that those extensions has been deprecated, but am running on a legacy system and need those